# Please help out. Its Cmakelist, Cmake error. I heard related articles to this but I couldnot solve it

Tags: ros, compilation, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im using ROS kinetic and trying to build my first HelloROS.cpp with rosserial_embeddedlinux package. I couldnot compile the package, (I dont know how to write a makefile or makefile is generated automatically after cmake )

this is the error:
Whenever i try to cmake,

```
/HelloROS.cpp:6:17: fatal error: ros.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/HelloROS.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/HelloROS.dir/examples/HelloRos/HelloROS.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloROS.dir/examples/HelloRos/HelloROS.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/HelloROS.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloROS.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**This is my cmakelist.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rosserial_embeddedlinux)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rosserial_client roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs 
)


catkin_package( 
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy  
    LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}/src/ros_lib)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
              
            ${rosserial_client_INCLUDE_DIRS}
           
            ${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            ${ros_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS})    

add_executable(HelloROS src/examples/HelloRos/HelloROS.cpp)
target_link_libraries(HelloROS ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(
  DIRECTORY src/ros_lib
            src/examples
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/src
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
)

catkin_install_python(
  PROGRAMS src/${PROJECT_NAME}/make_libraries.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

and

**this is my package.xml**

```
<package>
  <name>rosserial_embeddedlinux</name>
  <version>0.7.7</version>
  <description>
    rosserial for embedded Linux enviroments
  </description>
  <author>xx</author>
  <maintainer email="xx@gmail.com">xx</maintainer>
  <maintainer email="xx@.com">xx</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_embeddedlinux</url>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rosserial_client</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rosserial_msgs</run_depend>
</package>
```

Please out my issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277729/please-help-out.-its-cmakelist,-cmake-error.-i-heard-related-articles-to-this-but-i-couldnot-solve-it./) by [nishad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29985/nishad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The source Code ist Not given bitte likely you

```
#include <ros.h>
```

Rather than

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-10**:
`#include <ros.h>` is what the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_embeddedlinux/Tutorials/Example%20Publisher) shows.